# Theme settings not getting saved

Tags: 7, forms

I created custom settings for my theme for storing email, fb url, twitter url
and g+ url. Everything is coming properly but the settings are not getting saved.
I have no idea whats wrong. All the code and screenshots are below.

.info file content

```
settings[z_email] = mail@zed.com
settings[z_facebook] = fb/url
settings[z_twitter] = twitter/url
settings[z_gplus] = gplus/url
```

theme-settings.php file content

```
function z_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  $form['z_email'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#title'         => t('Email'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('mail@zealind.com'),
    '#description'   => t("Global Email Id for ZealInd site."),
  );

  $form['z_facebook'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#title'         => t('Facebook'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting(''),
    '#description'   => t("Facebook Url."),
  );

  $form['z_twitter'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#title'         => t('Twitter'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting(''),
    '#description'   => t("Twitter Url."),
  );

  $form['z_gplus'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#title'         => t('Google+'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting(''),
    '#description'   => t("Google+ Url."),
  );



}
```

The theme setting page:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not using [`theme_get_setting()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_get_setting/7) quite right at the moment; the first argument should be the name of the setting, not a default value.

For example, your element defined as `$form['z_email']` should look like this:

```
$form['z_email'] = array(
  '#type'          => 'textfield',
  '#title'         => t('Email'),
  '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('z_email'),
  '#description'   => t("Global Email Id for ZealInd site."),
);
```

Comment: This seems to be a little bit misleading. Actually the form inputs are getting saved successfully without any `'#default_value'`, but you need to set it to `theme_get_setting('setting_foo')` to display it (as input value).